# Ошибка в AndroidStudio при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, r.java-file

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Запускался правильно. Перестал запускаться после того, как скинула папку с проектом на другой компьютер.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Build – Clean project.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить дефис "-" на нижнее подчеркивание "_", и, соответственно, где переменная "e-mail" использовалась - заменить

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в панель `Gradle` справа, там запустите `Execute Gradle Task`, введите `clean` и выполните, затем снова запустите проект.

Comment: а как писать в gradle console? Я не могу ввести команду

Comment: @Bag ошибся, не Gradle Console, а Execute Gradle Task

Comment: осталась та же ошибка. Не помогло

Comment: @Bag это ваше название View?

Answer (score 0):

Дефис(-) нельзя употреблять в названии переменных, потому что компилятор интерпретирует его как знак минус или вычитание.На мой взгляд использовать название переменной как `EMAIL` будет вполне удобно.